# Mysql2::Error: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I receive a error whenever I try to do `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:migrate:redo`. I have done a search and could not find a similar solution to the issue that I am having. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the error:

```
rake db:migrate:redo
==  CreateConversations: reverting ============================================
-- drop_table(:conversations)
   -> 0.0310s
==  CreateConversations: reverted (0.0569s) ===================================

==  CreateConversations: migrating ============================================
-- create_table(:conversations)
   -> 0.0683s
==  CreateConversations: migrated (0.0686s) ===================================

==  CreateConversationsSummaries: migrating ===================================
-- execute("     CREATE VIEW conversation_summaries AS\n         SELECT c.id,\n         s.name as sender_name,\n         r.name as recipient_name,\n         m.body as most_recent_message_body,\n         m.created_at as most_recent_message_sent_at,\n         (select count(*) from messages AS m2 where m2.conversation_id = c.id) - 1 as reply_count\n         FROM conversations AS c\n         inner join users AS s on s.id = c.sender_id\n         inner join users AS r on r.id = c.recipient_id\n         left outer join (\n           select distinct (conversation_id), body, created_at\n           from messages AS m1\n           order by conversation_id, created_at desc\n         ) AS m ON m.conversation_id = c.id\n")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause:      CREATE VIEW conversation_summaries AS
         SELECT c.id,
         s.name as sender_name,
         r.name as recipient_name,
         m.body as most_recent_message_body,
         m.created_at as most_recent_message_sent_at,
         (select count(*) from messages AS m2 where m2.conversation_id = c.id) - 1 as reply_count
         FROM conversations AS c
         inner join users AS s on s.id = c.sender_id
         inner join users AS r on r.id = c.recipient_id
         left outer join (
           select distinct (conversation_id), body, created_at
           from messages AS m1
           order by conversation_id, created_at desc
         ) AS m ON m.conversation_id = c.id
```

My migration is:

```
    class CreateConversationsSummaries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
     CREATE VIEW conversation_summaries AS
         SELECT c.id,
         s.name as sender_name,
         r.name as recipient_name,
         m.body as most_recent_message_body,
         m.created_at as most_recent_message_sent_at,
         (select count(*) from messages AS m2 where m2.conversation_id = c.id) - 1 as reply_count
         FROM conversations AS c
         inner join users AS s on s.id = c.sender_id
         inner join users AS r on r.id = c.recipient_id
         left outer join (
           select distinct (conversation_id), body, created_at
           from messages AS m1
           order by conversation_id, created_at desc
         ) AS m ON m.conversation_id = c.id
     SQL
     end

  def down
    execute 'DROP VIEW conversation_summaries'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the aliases (AS) for your tables in the FROM clauses but that's not the point :). Also, I think you wanted `s` and `r` instead of `t` and `f` in your `INNER JOIN users`, respectively, if I am not mistaken :

```
CREATE VIEW conversation_summaries AS
    SELECT c.id,
    s.name as sender_name,
    r.name as recipient_name,
    m.body as most_recent_message_body,
    m.created_at as most_recent_message_sent_at,
    ((select count(*) from messages AS m2 where m2.conversation_id = c.id) - 1) as reply_count
    FROM conversations AS c
    inner join users AS s on s.id = c.sender_id
    inner join users AS r on r.id = c.recipient_id
    left outer join (
      select conversation_id, MAX(created_at)
      from messages AS m1
      group by conversation_id
    ) AS m ON m.conversation_id = c.id
SQL
end
```

You are doing an LEFT OUTER JOIN, but you select 3 fields which are `conversation_id, body, created_at`. Just select the greatest date which is `MAX(created_at)` and the `conversation_id`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `INNER JOIN users` mistake. I am still getting a error after adding (AS). `Mysql2::Error: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause:       CREATE VIEW conversation_summaries AS`. I updated original post with the current full error.

Comment: That does not work. I'm trying other solutions too. There's 1 small piece I have to be missing. I updated original post.